# Web Speech API - Speech recognition in iOS

Tags: html, ios7, safari, webspeech-api

HTML5 has a new Speech recognition API and caniuse.com suggestes, Safari iOS 7.1 supports this API. But, I have tried it and its not working on iOS (iPhone 5S) with Safari 7.1 or MAC OS x safari 7.1.

Is there any workaround to make it work on iOS and Android? Is this speech recognition API be used for sensitive data as it uses Google Services ().

I tried this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Web Speech API Demo</title>
<head>
    <script>
        function test(){
          alert("Called test")
            if ('speechSynthesis' in window) {
             alert("Synthesis support. Make your web apps talk!");
           }

        if ('SpeechRecognition' in window) {
          alert("Speech recognition support. Talk to your apps!");
        }
        else{
            alert("No support");
        }
        if (document.createElement('input').webkitSpeech === undefined) {
            alert("Nooooo")
            // Not supported
        } else {
            // Supported!
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am having the same issue, in that I am getting the error from Safari it does not understand SpeechRecognition, but it does speechSynthesis.  Have you had any luck with this ?

Comment: not yet,,..I don't think Safari supports it yet!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I am pretty bummed about this as well. Here was where I found that safari/IE are not supported..

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API